# Azure Functions: Timeout When I Call "func new"

Tags: bash, macos, azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-core-tools

I have been following [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local) to install Azure functions locally. However, when I run `func new`, it hangs for a minute and fails:

```
% func new
One or more errors occurred. (A task was canceled.)
```

I think I installed the CLI correctly, because when I just run `func`, I get the expected output:

```
% func
...
Azure Functions Core Tools
Core Tools Version:       3.0.3477 Commit hash: 5fbb9a76fc00e4168f2cc90d6ff0afe5373afc6d  (64-bit)
Function Runtime Version: 3.0.15584.0

Usage: func [context] [context] <action> [-/--options]
...
```

Any idea what is happening?

Answer (score 1):

try use powershall instead of CMD

***func new***

mostly you will get error like
func : File ***\AppData\Roaming\npm\func.ps1 cannot be loaded. The file
***\AppData\Roaming\npm\func.ps1 is not digitally signed. You cannot run this script on the current
system. For more information about running scripts and setting execution policy, see about_Execution_Policies at
https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1

- func new
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
  ```

to Fix this run
**Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy Bypass**

now try again it should work for u